# Retry Branch.io after connectivity error

Tags: android, splash-screen, branch.io

We initialize Branch in the splash screen and we set a little time out to move the user to the Login or Main screen after a couple of seconds with no response from Branch.

I the case of Branch not responding or Branch time out `Trouble initializing Branch. Branch API Error: poor network connectivity. Please try again later.`

How can I retry branch from a different Activity?
(remember we move the user to Login or Main after a couple of seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Branch already a retry logic in place and if there are connectivity issues, the Branch initSession will try to connect to Branch servers 3 times. You can custom define the number of retries you wish to make in case there are any issues initializing Branch.

Here is the sample code:

```
branch = Branch.getInstance();
//set retry count
branch.setRetryCount(5);
branch.initSession(new Branch.BranchReferralInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referringParams, BranchError error) {
            if (error == null) {

            } else {
                Log.i("MyApp", error.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }, this.getIntent().getData(), this);
```

If instead, you wish to retry in some other activity, you could probably make the initSession call again you Main or Login Activity. But you may or may not get link params in the second activity because maybe the first Activity already consumed them, so you would need to put a check in place to ensure that if Branch is initialized in the Splash Activity, do not initialize Branch again in the Main or Login Activity.

Comment: If there is an issue connecting to Branch in the splash screen, what can I do in Login to "do it again" and get the data? Branch.getInstance().getLatestReferringParams() ? Are you suggesting to only initialize Branch once (only in Splash screen)?

Comment: If you wish to retry in the Login Activity, you can call branch.initSession() again in the Login Activity.
As I mentioned in my post, just make sure you are not initializing branch twice, since if Branch does initialized in the Splash Activity, the initialization in the Login Activity will not return any link parameters.
Also make sure, to add the intent filters in both activities to handle the Branch link parameters.